# How to translate "to turn on/out the light, the TV, in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

Since electricity is something new,how can we express this in latin? I guess the verbs *accendo* and *solvo* aren't exactly precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep `illuminare` and `exstinguere`.

The simpler, the better.

Remember that when electricity was discovered, our languages did not possess the proper words either. We had to proceed by analogy with fire.

Sticking to the original stems allows one to remain faithful to the original metaphors. Accordingly, I think periphrases can be awkward.

Now if you want to go the English way, you need to find something with *vertere*; however, the *on* and *off* predicative particles do not have Latin counterparts, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you. They make sense now.

Comment: What about with the using the latin equivalents of *encender* and *apagar* of the Spanish?

Comment: @Dolphínus With *incendere* you bring the notion of "burning", which could be confusing. The etymology of apagar is unclear and I do not speak Spanish so I couldn't tell.

Comment: In Spanish for say burn you would say quemar. [apagar comes from the Latin pacāre](https://dle.rae.es/apagar)

Comment: an what about the Deutsche weg with an and aus wich is like in and out?